# Pre Build step in automake project

Tags: linux, autoconf, automake

In an automake and autoconf project how would you add a custom pre-build step. I need to run a command before make is ran to update a files timestamp to ensure it gets built on every build.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a file to be regenerated on every 'make' invocation, this makefile idiom will do the job:

```
always_build_me: FORCE
        # commands

FORCE: # no dependencies or commands
.PHONY: FORCE # hint for gnu make, ignored by others
```

However, that you need this suggests that `always_build_me` changes each time it is rebuilt, which is a bad practice.  Your build process should be fully deterministic -- that is, if you haven't changed the sources, rebuilding from scratch should produce exactly the same bits it did the last time.

Comment: I agree, but is there a good way to test if any of the sources have changed and then force the particular file only when a file changed?

Comment: If that's what you want, why don't normal makefile dependencies work?